# Figura triangular con css

Tags: css

Como puedo hacer la siguiente figura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

probe con border-radius pero lo vuelve redondo la punta y los lados los curbea, necesito que la punta sea recta y que no sean curvas los lados.

mi codigo es:

```css
.Back {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius:20px 20px 0 0 ;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Back">
</div>
```

Comment: Debes subir el código que has intentado usar para poderte ayudar !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede intentar lo siguiente:

```css
#contForm{
  width: 270px;
}

#topForm{
    width: 150px;
    height: 0px;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid #428bca;
}

#bottomForm{
   height: 250px;
   background-color: #428bca;
}
```

```html
<div id="contForm">
  <div id="topForm"></div>
  <div id="bottomForm"></div>
</div>
```